# Quitar el Javascript que bloquea la visualización del contenido

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

cuando hago mis webs las paso por Google Speeds, siempre me muestra el error de "Quitar el Javascript que bloquea la visualización del contenido".
He intentado eliminar este error moviendo el jquery al footer u otra sección de mi web, ya que actualmente lo tengo en el head `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`
Este código no lo puedo poner en el footer ya que si lo hago así no me carga el bxSlider que tengo implementado, y por consiguiente la web no funciona.

He probado a instalar el plungin Autoptimize pero al seleccionar la casilla de optimizar js, veo el análisis de google y me baja 10 puntos(asi que lo descarto).

Tengo instalado W3 Total Caché, pero al seleccionar optimizar js no hace nada... (adjunto imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Podéis darme alguna solución para solucionar este problema ?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <title>
            <?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );?>
        </title>
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
        <link rel="icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/favicon.png" type="image/png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/less/theme/plantillas/estilos.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/less/theme/plantillas/font/stylesheet.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/less/theme/plantillas/font/icons.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
        
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/less/theme/plantillas/jquery.bxslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-LOx49zn73f7YUs15NNJTDnzEyPFLOGc7A7pfuICtTMc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://prueba.es/web/wp-content/themes/modo/js/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://prueba.es/web/wp-content/themes/modo/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

        <?php wp_head();?>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/wow.min.js"></script>
        <script> new WOW().init();</script>
        
    </head>
```

Comment: Hola Antonio Ángel, deberías incluir algo más de código (un [mcve]), para que podamos ver el problema completo. ¿Por qué dices que no puedes mover el código? ¿no puedes mover el bxSlider también? ¿Has probado a usar `async` o `defer` a la hora de incluir tus scripts?

Comment: Vaya por delante que te tienes que fiar de google speeds lo justo, tirando a nada, y analizar la velocidad con el network del inspector segun tu propio criterio. Hay paginas muy rapidas que puntuan peor que paginas muy lentas porque google speed no comprueba realmente la velocidad de la pagina sino ciertas caracteristicas del codigo.
Dicho esto, estas cargando dos veces jquery y cargando un jquery migrate que me juego el bigote  que no necesitas, empieza por limpiar y optimizar el codigo...si pegas el codigo de la pagina sera más facil ayudarte

Comment: Si tu código deja de funcionar por mover los scripts abajo, algo tienes muy mal montado: precisamente una de las razones de tenerlo abajo es asegurarte de que todo el HTML se ha procesado y el DOM ha sido generado

Comment: ademas de lo que te comenta @PabloLozano, le da una sensacion de velocidad porque al cargar el DOM primero el usuario ya visualiza algo

Comment: El orden en el que cargas las librerías podría ser importante por lo que moverlas abajo no debería hacerse sin ton ni son. Como te sugirieron previamente incluye un [mcve].

Comment: es un theme propio? como registras el jquery y bxslider ? (según el reporte estás cargando dos jquerys 1.12 y 1.9)  si es por functions.php incluye la seccion donde haces el hook para registrar los scripts (tal vez haya que desregistrar algunos y cambiar las dependencias)